# Tkinter insert function inserts text on to the same line all the time even when I change the line I input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

```py
    scoreboard = tkinter.Text(window)
    scoreboard["state"] = "normal"
    scoreboard.pack()

    for count, name, score in zip(range(len(names)), names, scores):
        scoreboard.insert(str(float(count+1)), f"{count+1}. {name}    {score}/10")

    scoreboard["state"] = "disabled"
```

For example:
If names = ["user2", "user1"]
and scores = [3,0]

It yields: [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB1Di.jpg)
Where the highlighted text should have been under the first line.

I also verified that str(float(1)) = "1.0" so I don't get why this doesn't work.

Plus, I need this to work with arrays of any size so please don't tell me to insert it manually.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of computing the index, always insert at the end, and be sure to add a newline after each line. If you don't want the extra newline at the end you can always trim it off after the fact.

```
for count, name, score in zip(range(len(names)), names, scores):
    scoreboard.insert("end", f"{count+1}. {name}    {score}/10\n")
scoreboard.delete("end-1c")
```

Comment: I would've upvoted but I don't have enough rep. Thank you very much, that worked!